# Export BigQuery logging: which resource types to select (and what is the difference between them?)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-logging

I want to export relevant BigQuery (audit) logging to a BQ dataset.

So I have to create a log sink for that.

I found a blog that sets up the BQ logging only using `bigquery_project` or `bigquery_dataset`:
https://dataform.co/blog/exporting-bigquery-usage-logs

I noticed that there are several more resource.types to query on:

- bigquery_project
- bigquery_resource
- bigquery_dataset
- bigquery_table
- bigquery_dts_config
- bigquery_dts_run
- bigquery_biengine_model

I found that list here:
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list#resource-types

So the last three have to do with data transfer and biengine.

But I wonder what is the difference between `project`, `resource` and `dataset`?

What info is in those 3 different kinds of logs?
And: which of the three (or which of the seven resource types) should I use?

[image: log sink for exporting BQ logs]

Comment: AuditData payload will return resource.type set to bigquery_resource, not bigquery_dataset. In BigQueryAuditMetadata messages, resource.type is set to one of these values: `bigquery_dataset` for operations to datasets such as `google.cloud.bigquery.v2.DatasetService.*`, resource.labels.dataset_id contains the encapsulating dataset and `bigquery_project` for all other called methods, such as jobs resource.labels.location contains the location of the job. For more information you can refer this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs#bigqueryauditmetadata_format).

Comment: Hi @SandervandenOord, Is the above comment helpful?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT it was somewhat helpful, but am also hoping for examples of useful data to extract from all these different resource.types

Comment: Hi @SandervandenOord, If you find my answer helpful, please consider to accept it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their researches.

Answer (score 2):

[AuditData payload](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/rest/Shared.Types/AuditData) will return resource.type set to bigquery_resource, not bigquery_dataset. In BigQueryAuditMetadata messages, resource.type is set to one of the following values:
`bigquery_dataset` for operations to datasets such as `google.cloud.bigquery.v2.DatasetService.*` such as resource.labels.dataset_id contains the encapsulating dataset and `bigquery_project` for all other called methods, such as jobs resource.labels.location contains the location of the job.

`resource.type="bigquery_project" AND logName:"cloudaudit.googleapis.com"` is used to get BigQuery audit logs for a project.

`resource.type="bigquery_dataset" AND logName:"cloudaudit.googleapis.com"`
is used to get BigQuery audit logs for a dataset.

`resource.type="bigquery_dts_config" AND logName:"cloudaudit.googleapis.com"`
is used to get BigQuery audit logs for a Data Transfer Service configuration.

`resource.type="bigquery_dts_run" AND logName:"cloudaudit.googleapis.com"` is used to get BigQuery audit logs for a Data Transfer Service.

`resource.type="bigquery_biengine_model" AND  logName:"cloudaudit.googleapis.com"` is used to get BigQuery audit logs for BI Engine Model.

**Example:**

To show log entries from a given transfer config_id, in the Query builder, add the following filter:

```
resource.type="bigquery_dts_config"
labels.run_id="transfer_config_id"
```

For more information you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs#bigqueryauditmetadata_format).